# How to keep Google Maps in obfuscation?

Tags: android, google-maps, obfuscation, android-proguard

I have implemented Google Maps (Google API) in my application. So I added ProGuard file inside my application. After adding the Proguard file, the map is not opening, and showing a white blank screen.

This is my Proguard code:

```
-keep class * implements com.google.android.gms.maps { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
```

I have tried this, but it's not working.

Comment: Do you have a logcat? There might be some useful info in there.

Comment: If it's a problem with the obfuscation, your project will never run, instead it will generate compile Error. I think that your problem is with Google map Key

Comment: for direct installation it is working fine . for APK installation not working

Comment: Double check your map key is signed with your signed apk keystore

Comment: keystore perfect. if i remove progaurd file it is working fine. so problem is in obfuscation

Comment: can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `Google Maps API` uses some other stuff as well which can cause problems during obfuscation, like custom Parcelables and serialization. These rules should work:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static *** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Source: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/proguard-rules.pro

According to @Fakher in the comments:

Also note that your API key needs to be correct, Google only show you a visible Map if you have requested an API key and added it in your application.

Comment: Check your API key, do you have one?

Comment: API key is perfect